# WTForms, Jinja2, Flask - creating subform that is connected to another form

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm creating a little project that's using MongoDB via flask server on Linux.

Now I'm stuck because I need retrieve data from forms in specific structure that corresponds with MongoDB database.

Problem is that I need to create form via WTFform that connects to another form.

These are the data I have in MongoDB:

```
{'name': 'Marek', 
'Surname': 'Novak', 
'qualifiaction': ['PHP', 'SQL', 'Python', 'VBA'], 
'Another_Qualification': {'Programing': ['Pandas repository', 'Jinja2'] 'Database': ['SQL', 'NoSQL']}}
```

This is the page I was able to create:
[image: WEB image]

Export that I'm able to make is:

```
{'Name': ['Marek'], 'Surename': ['Novak'], 'qualification': ['PHP', 'SQL', 'Python', 'VBA'], 'Another_Qualification': ['programing'], 'StaticKey': ['Pandas', 'Jinja2'], 's': ['Submit Label']}
```

So in my opinion problem can be solved by changing Key value 'StaticKey' to value that's dynamically changing by VALUE inserted into Another_Qalification form. Problem that I can't solve is that the key value is by name of a form. EZ way is to tell that form name which is 'StaticKey' can dinamicaly change to VALUE that are added in Another_Qualification.

Can you help me How can I Create 2 forms where 1 is subform from another. Thanks.